# Did I discover an easy way to make money via PayPal and cashback credit card? If so, is it legal and is the money taxable?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, credit-card, paypal, reward-program

Here it is: I send money to a family member via PayPal using my credit card, PayPal charges a fee but the cash back I get from the PayPal transaction exceeds the PayPal fee, my family member sends me the money back for free.

My concern is that my card might process sending money via PayPal to a friend differently from how it processes payments to a merchant via PayPal. For instance, it could count as a cash advance and that would likely incur other fees. Furthermore, I don't want to break any laws or agreements.

Edit: A customer service representative said that the card processes a PayPal payment to friends or family as it would a purchase.

Comment: Why not try it with a small amount for starters and report back to ell us know how it worked out? If you do end up making money, do a large transaction ASAP before PayPay discovers the loophole and closes it promptly.

Comment: Why would PayPal give your friend more money than the amount you paid? That makes no sense.

Comment: Why do you care whether PayPal or your credit card company is the one who  loses money as long as it isn't you who is losing money? Do it quick, waking up your sleepyhead cousin if you need to, because _someone_ is going to notice the flood of transactions as the rest of the readership of money.SE starts cashing in on the deal you have discovered and your window of opportunity is going to slam shut very soon.

Comment: Are you sure the cashback is higher than the fee? What is your cashback rate and what is the PayPal fee?

Comment: @user253751 That's not what I said

Comment: Which credit card do you have that is giving 5% cashback on everything?

Comment: Probably one with rotating rewards groups

Comment: @BenMiller-RememberMonica: Who said it was on everything?

Comment: @BenVoigt I’m having a hard time believing that this month’s bonus category is “Paying a friend with PayPal” :)

Comment: @BenMiller-RememberMonica: Believe it.  "qualifying purchases are those made through the PayPal wallet online, **when you send money to Friends and Family via PayPal using your Discover Card**, and point-of-sale transactions using PayPal Here"  https://www.discover.com/credit-cards/cashback-bonus/cashback-calendar.html  (emphasis mine)

Comment: The transaction limit implies to me that Discover or PayPal (or the combination, they could have collaborated on this) decided that allowing this was an acceptable premium to get people used to sending money this way.  It is really no different from the $100 or so promotions to get you to take and use a new credit card.  There are people who search for the premiums on getting new credit cards to collect the rewards.  Check the fine print, there may be a limit on how many times you can do this, but go for it.

Comment: @BenVoigt Wow. That’s quite a gimmicky promo. Thanks for the info.

Comment: @BenMiller-RememberMonica: Not really a promo, as it has appeared for one quarter (3 months) in each of the last few years.

Answer (score 61):

**Update (2022):** It may be possible to earn double cash back for new accounts in the first year. I cannot find anything in the terms or conditions that would exclude this. If that's the case and you maxed out the offer, then you could add an additional $75 to your profit listed below.

Congrats! You found a legitimate arbitrage situation that indeed could make you some money.  These are increasingly rare, which does make it kind of cool, even if you end up not taking advantage of it. IMHO it's not worth it due to the spending cap.

The deal you **Discover**ed appears to pay 5% on PayPal transactions, including those made to friends and family, but unfortunately it is capped at $1500. So, the maximum cash back you can achieve is $75. The minimum the PayPal fees would be is 2.9% + $0.30 for a single transaction, which is $43.80. Your profit from this would be $31.20 minus whatever you have to give to your friend to convince them to go along with it and give you your money back.

In the US, cash back on purchases from individuals (but not businesses) is typically treated as a discount on your purchase, and is not taxable.

Here's the fine print of the deal:
[image]

Comment: "typically treated"

Comment: And good luck in convincing people, as this is the setup for a well known scam.

Comment: @PiKindOfGuy yeah, that's a little vague... The main type of rewards that are taxable are sign-up bonuses that aren't associated with a particular purchase. Cash back is considered a discount because you are purchasing with after-tax money. More info here: https://www.investopedia.com/ask/answers/110614/are-credit-card-rewards-considered-taxable-income-irs.asp An exception might be if you used a CC to donate to a charity, and then took a tax deduction for that amount. If you then receive cash back on that purchase, you would technically have to reduce the amount of the deduction you took.

Comment: @vsz If it's someone you know well, and you can show them all the information showing this is a real thing, it might not be too hard.

Comment: Could the friend you send it to not similarly get cash back from sending the cash back to you? Which would provide their incentive.

Comment: Since sending money to your friend is not a purchase (and the OP even gets it back), I doubt the "cash back" is tax free here.

Comment: Could it be a breach of contract/TOS though? Could PayPal and/or your bank decide to ban you from their services?

Comment: @PedroA Even if they could, they probably wouldn't bother. $32/year is a drop in the bucket. It would probably cost them more to investigate and discover the scheme. And the same with the IRS investigating if it's taxable.

Comment: @Mohirl yes, if the friend also signs up for the Discover card.

Comment: In other words, you can get a reward of tens of dollars for the time, hassle, and risk of moving around thousands of dollars with a person you really trust. It would probably be more lucrative to just find a part time job.

Comment: @PedroA PayPal wouldn't care bc they make a profit off of this. And I believe Discover would happily pay $30 for every new CC customer.

Comment: Sounds like $15.60 each to me!

Comment: @vsz Maybe scam artists are actually good-willed people that find loopholes like this but then run into unexpected pitfalls so they're too ashamed to return less to you than you invested so they're holding out for the next great loophole like this one 

Comment: Even if this is legitimate, it looks a heck of a lot like money-laundering. The financial and personal costs associated with a legal defense probably aren't worth the effort.

Comment: @jpaugh The point of money laundering is to take money you obtained illegally, and make it look like you obtained it legally, usually so you can pay taxes on it, and then keep/spend the rest. This scheme is actually conceptually the opposite. The money is obtained legally, and taxes are (probably) not being paid. Note if you made a serious profit from this you should be treating it as income and paying taxes.

Comment: @TTT If doing something perfectly normal and legal appears superficially like money laundering (that is, because it involves a series of unorthodox transfers, and an "accomplice"), it could still trigger an investigation by the bank or FBI. The fact that it may be determined to be legal in the end doesn't avoid the headache of explaining it. Not worth it for $75, not worth it for $500!

Comment: @jpaugh I wonder if you're using the wrong term? Money laundering almost always uses untraceable *cash* transactions. Electronic transfers are traceable. It's possible that weird electronic transfers could raise flags for reasons such as scam attempts, which is what it sounds like you're referring to. But that is not called money laundering. Also, electronically sending thousands of dollars back and forth between friends would not be suspicious at all. That's pretty common.

Answer (score 11):

Many years ago some US bank gave you air miles for cash withdrawals, and a couple took out all their savings in cash, paid it back in, drew it all out again and repeat. They managed to withdraw about 7 million dollars, obviously also paid in 7 million, getting tons of air miles, until the bank acted.

That was apparently totally legal.

Comment: See also https://www.businessinsider.com/us-mint-ends-the-dollar-coin-scam-for-airline-miles-2011-7?r=US&IR=T

Comment: Of course it was legal.   Why would a company's poorly thought out marketing scheme be illegal to take advantage of?  One thing that might be triggered is an investigation of deposits of $10,000+, but as there is a perfectly fine paper trail as to the source of the money, it wouldn't trigger any legal action.

Comment: Or see the infamous Hoover Air Miles promotion in the UK https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoover_free_flights_promotion.  Hoover offered free £600 flights from UK to US for a purchase of £100 or more.  They were surprised how many people took them up on it!

Answer (score 10):

Yes, and it falls into the same category as banks paying you money to open a checking account with them.

Businesses call this "customer acquisition costs" and they work pretty hard to enumerate it to a specific number.  They can tell you it costs them on average $231.14 in marketing costs to land a new customer (or whatever the figure is for them).

Sometimes this can be direct; banks used to give out toasters for opening a new account. PBS gives out tote bags.

So some bright bulb in the marketing department said "hey, why don't we just pay this money to our customers directly?"  Because people would rather have money than a toaster.  You've seen 1000 variations on this... This promotion of PayPal's is cut from that cloth.

As TTT points out, PayPal has installed practical limits to the promotion, which make it "not worth the trouble" to do it in the manner you plan.   However it works out rather nicely to use the promotion the way PayPal intends: to just buy stuff you're gonna buy anyway, *but instead, use PayPal to pay for it*.

That is precisely the goal: to acclimate you into the idea of using PayPal in ways you've never used before.  The idea is, you'll find it so convenient you'll keep doing it once the promotion runs out.

Answer (score 3):

I am not a lawyer but I suspect that if the finance/legal bods at your credit card company and/or paypal realized this was going on they would consider it to be a form of cash advance.

Paypal explicitly prohibits the use of PayPal accounts as a means of obtaining cash advances. IIRC Credit card companies often also reserve the right to treat a transaction that is effectively a cash advance as one, even if it was reported through the payment network as a purchase.

> In connection with your use of our websites, your PayPal account, the PayPal services, > or in the course of your interactions with PayPal, other PayPal customers, or third
> parties, you must not:
> <--snip other prohibitions-->
> Provide yourself a cash advance from your credit card (or help others to do so);

Comment: There is explicit support for sending money to friends using a credit card, both on the Paypal side (where the fee of 2.9% is assessed, which is comparable to cash advance fees) and on the Discover Bank side, where they specifically say that the 5% cashback applies to using the Discover credit card to send money through Paypal to friends.  So no, it is not prohibited, and both the credit card company and Paypal know exactly what is going on.  Unless you are arguing that receiving money from the friend at some future point changes the send money transaction from encouraged to prohibited?

Comment: Clearly the rule in the paypal rules can't be aimed at properly documented cash advances since paypal doesn't offer those. So it must be aimed at combinations of transactions that effectively form a cash advance.

Comment: In practice of course if you use your paypal account once to give a friend a cash advance will almost certainly get away with it because paypal can't easilly tell the difference between a bona-fide personal payment and. OTOH if you do it on a large scale I suspect paypal will start asking questions (and freezing your account if you don't provide satisfactory answers).